# Best way to download a file in PHP

Tags: php

Which would be the best way to download a file from another domain in PHP?
i.e. A zip file.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest one is [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents), a more advanced way would be with [cURL](http://php.net/curl) for example. You can store the data to your harddrive with [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/file_put_contents).

Comment: gotta be careful with file_get_contents() though. All of that data is held in a string. PHP's default memory limit is usually fairly low (16M IIRC), so if he's on shared hosting and the said files he's downloading are fairly large... he's gonna have a hard time with that.

Comment: unless you have a nice shared host and he will bump the memory for you on PHP, or you have your own server. Even then it's still kind of an iffy idea.

Comment: Also, file_get_contents is disabled on more secure boxes to avoid hacker attempts when trying to access files on other domains.

Comment: => Use file_get_contents() for small files and cURL for bigger downloads.

Answer (score 4):

normally, the fopen functions work for remote files too, so you could do the following to circumvent the memory limit (but it's slower than file_get_contents)

```
<?php
$remote = fopen("http://www.example.com/file.zip", "rb");
$local = fopen("local_name_of_file.zip", 'w');
while (!feof($remote)) {
  $content = fread($remote, 8192);
  fwrite($local, $content);
}
fclose($local);
fclose($remote);
?>
```

copied from here: http://www.php.net/fread

Answer (score 1):

You may use one code line to do this:

```
copy(URL, destination);
```

This function returns TRUE on success and FALSE on failure.

Comment: I just profiled it on php7.4/unix, copy() has the same small memory footprint, and same execution speed, as a fread/fwrite loop. (unlike file_get_contents/file_put_contents that has a much higher memory footprint and slower execution).
So this should be the accepted answer.