# download file from absolute path (other domain)

Tags: php, url, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to download a file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728458/best-way-to-download-a-file-in-php)

i have been asked to download several videos in a format like:

```
http://website.com/asset/v00/488/618.asx
```

and i can't find the way (with save as.. is not posible and all this youtube download services say that 'service is unknown'). Can i do it with some php script?

it would be great to be able to call a funcion like:

```
function downloadFile($url){
   //prompt download

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files are big, you'll have to use fopen() to read the content of the incoming data as you write it to disk:

```
$fp = fopen('http://website.com/asset/v00/488/618.asx', 'r');
$fpl = fopen('local/618.asx', 'w');
while(!feof($fp)){
    fwrite($fpl, fread($fp, 1024));
}
fclose($fp);
fclose($fpl);
```

Else, if the file is small, you can just file_get_contents() it to your memory and then dump it using file_put_contents()...

Comment: what's big or small in kb?? this code gives me: Warning: fopen(http://thomson.co.uk/asset/v00/488/618.asx) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /home/toni005/public_html/toniweb.us/downloader/d.php on line 6

Warning: fopen() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/toni005/public_html/toniweb.us/downloader/d.php on line 9
(infinite times and the memory of my computer collapses)

Comment: Big is more than a few MBs cause thats what you'll have available for your memory process. This is, depending on the server, between 8 and 32 MBs. You forgot the second parameter, thats what your error says. The second parameter is 'w' for the write portion or 'r' for the read portion...