# Downloading & saving files to disk

Tags: web-scraping

I want to download some files programatically from a remote server.

If you can write the code-snippet in VB, VB.NET, Java, or PHP I can try to solve the rest by myself.

Sample file address:

- www.example.com/file1.pdf
- www.example.com/file2.pdf
- www.example.com/file%20n-1.pdf

It will be helpful if you give solutions to this problem in PHP so I can test in WAMP.

Comment: [PHP snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728458/best-way-to-download-a-file-in-php)

Comment: [VB 6.0 Snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976152/download-file-vb6)

Comment: Adding some source code, or what you have tried would be better. Check StackOverflow FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use HttpWebRequest to download file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778055/how-to-use-httpwebrequest-to-download-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP example

```
<?php
$files = array('file1.pdf', 'file2.pdf', 'filen.pdf');

$remoteBase = 'http://www.site.com/';
$localBase = 'downloads/';

foreach( $files as $f ) {
    $fp = fopen($remoteBase.$f, 'rb');
    if ( !$fp ) {
        echo 'error, ', $f, "\n";
    }
    else {
        file_put_contents($localBase.$f, $fp);
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In VB.NET, [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0f69eh.aspx) makes this trivial:

```
new WebClient().DownloadFile(url, filename)
```

Comment: a little bit code snippet will be appreciated !!

Comment: @Sourav: That *is* a code snippet - all you need are the `url` and `filename` variables, and `WebClient` will do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you may use `java.net.URL` and `java.net.URLConnection` class methods.

SO Thread - [How to download and save a file from internet using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java).

Comment: a little bit code snippet will be appreciated.